# Remove top line from csv and then merge

Tags: shell-script

I have multiple similar csv files at one location. I have to merge those files into  one file. But the problem is my csv files have one additional line at the top of the headers. I want to remove that line and then merge the csv.

I know i can do something like below when there is no extra line at the top.

```
cat *UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merged_UNSTRUCTURED.csv
```

But the challenge is how to i remove that top line. Also, all the files name will have a pattern like UNSTRUCTURED.

[image]

Comment: `sed 1d file` deletes the first line of a file. However with more than one file, only the first line of the first file is affected. With GNU `sed` you can do `sed -s 1d *UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merge_UNSTRUCTURED.csv` to treat each file separately.

Comment: Thanks Philippos!! Let me try that.

Comment: The provided command is also adding the header from the second file as value.

Comment: Added csv, the line with If is garbage

Comment: @user3901666 doest the column 2 and 3 are static value? will be the same in all rows?

Comment: `sed '1,2d' *UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merge_UNSTRUCTURED.csv` should do the trick then.

Comment: Hi mark, 
The provided command is not working as expected.

Comment: ooops.  Forgot the `-s`, sorry.  `sed -s '1,2d' *UNSTRUCTURED.csv > Merge_UNSTRUCTURED.csv`.  This is basically @Philippos solution, just deleting one line more.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This works fine!!

Comment: Also, for normal merging of multiple csv files with same header ( and result should have just one header from any file) i am using below:
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *STRUCTURED_PROD.csv > Merged_STRUCTURED_PROD.csv                                    Is this correct?

Comment: `awk 'FNR > 1 || NR == 1` would be more efficient as `NR == 1` is almost always false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `cat`, use:

```
awk 'FNR>2 || NR==2' ./*UNSTRUCTURED.csv > UNSTRUCTURED-Merged.csv
```

Which skips the first 2 lines (that extra line and the header line) of all files but preserves the second line (header) of the first.

`NR` is the record number in the whole input (*records* being *lines* by default) while `FNR` is the record number in the current file.

To remove the first 2 lines from *all* files (resulting in an output with no header), just use `awk 'FNR>2'` or with GNU `sed`: `sed -s 1,2d` or with GNU `tail` or compatible (including ast-open, FreeBSD and busybox): `tail -qn+3`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, but all my files have that one extra line and the header is from line 2 . So, the script should remove the first line and the merged file should have the actual header i.e. line 2

Comment: @user3901666, do you mean that the header is on line 2 (which must be skipped from all but the first file) and line 1  is garbage which needs to be removed from all files? Then that would be `awk 'FNR>2 || NR==2'`

Comment: yes, line 1 is garbage and must be removed from all files and the actual header starts from line 2.

Comment: @user3901666, do you mean that the header  takes up more than one line (*from line 2* to ... which line?).

Comment: no header is just line 2...garbage is line 1 and the values start from line 3..
This is the case in all the files.

Comment: @user3901666. OK, then the latest edit should address it. You may want to clarify your question as to what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Added sample csv as well for refernce, the line starts with if is garbage

Comment: This is working perfect. Thanks Stephane!!